# Change TabIndex with Storyboard

Tags: wpf, xaml, storyboard, tabcontrol, tabindex

Is there a way to change the TabIndex (in XAML only) when a button is clicked.
Below is my try following [this article](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/event-based-property-changes) and one on my own which is commented.
Thanks!

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="Button" Content="Go" />
    <TabControl x:Name="Tab">
        <TabItem Header="First">
            <TextBlock Text="First" />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Second">
            <TextBlock Text="Second" />
        </TabItem>
        <TabControl.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames
                            Duration="0"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="Tab"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="TabIndex">
                            <DiscreteInt32KeyFrame
                                KeyTime="0"
                                Value="1" />
                        </Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <!--<Int32Animation
                            Duration="0"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="Tab" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="TabIndex"
                            FillBehavior="HoldEnd"
                            By="1"
                            From="0"
                            To="1" />-->
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </TabControl.Triggers>
    </TabControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Edit: Use **SelectedIndex** instead of **TabIndex**  to change the current tab.

Comment: What else you want it to be?

Comment: @RohitVats I just want it to work. I think I didn't understand you. The problem is that the current attempts to change the TabIndex are always failure. Somthing is wrong with the storyboard, but I do not see it.

Comment: You have explicitly set value to 1 in storyboard here `Value="1"`.

Comment: @RohitVats I should remove the "interesting fact".
Yes, I have explicitly set the value to 1, which is my idea but it doesn't work. The value TabIndex is still Int.MaxValue. The problem is that the whole storyboard is not working...

Comment: Now i got it what you want to achieve. Please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event trigger is misplaced. Instead of placing the trigger on `TabControl`, place trigger on `StackPanel`.

```
<StackPanel.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
               <Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                             Storyboard.TargetName="Tab"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="TabIndex">
                   <DiscreteInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                          Value="1" />
               </Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
         </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</StackPanel.Triggers>
```

***Reason***:

`Button.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` is a ***tunnelling routed attached event*** i.e. *it will start from root element and continue to tunnel until it reaches actual sender*. So, it will start from window or UserControl and will continue to tunnel until it reaches Go button. It won't tunnel to TabControl since it is sibling of button and not a parent of TabControl.

But it will work if you place it on `StackPanel` since StackPanel is parent of TabControl and Button. *Before tunnelling to GO Button, it will pass via StackPanel*. Hence, your storyBoard will work.

Comment: Thank you! Just want to add that I'm using TabIndex instead of SelectedIndex(my mistake) and that won't change the current tab. Your explanation is perfect.